# How to delete a macro

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have a macro in Notepad++ that I don't use any more, the macro also uses a shortcut I want to use for other macro's. But there seems to be no function in Notepad++ to delete macro's. Is there a another way to delete macro's in Notepad++ (for instance manipulating the setting-files of Notepad++)?

Comment: There is always a more difficult way of doing most anything one could hope to accomplish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried this:

1. From the top menu, select “Settings” => “Shortcut Mapper…” and scroll down near the very bottom
2. Right-click and select either Modify or Delete

Comment: There's now a dedicated 'Macro. tab.